# MySQL setting a column to null doesn't work

Tags: mysql

This SQL query gives this error: [1 errors were found during analysis. Unrecognized keyword. (near "NULL" at position 47)]

```
UPDATE `article` SET `article`.`SAISIE_DATE` = NULL WHERE `article`.`SAISIE_DATE` = '0000-00-00'
```

What I've tried so far these two queries, and they actually work:

```
UPDATE `article` SET `article`.`SAISIE_DATE` = NULL WHERE `article`.`IDARTICLE` = 19

SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE `article`.`SAISIE_DATE` = '0000-00-00'
```

Table structure:

[image]

Comment: it should work `UPDATE article SET SAISIE_DATE = NULL WHERE SAISIE_DATE = '0000-00-00'`

Comment: I've already tried that of course, same problem.

Comment: did you got any error?

Comment: same error message

Comment: *This SQL query gives this error: [1 errors were found during analysis. Unrecognized keyword. (near "NULL" at position 47)]* This is **NOT** MySQL error message. This is client's pre-parsing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `0` instead of `0000-00-00`.

Allowing or forbidding a zero date is a conscious choice. (You may be aware of this already, or be converting zero dates to null to prepare to change the setting. Future visitors may not be aware).

See more about this setup at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html.

A relevant extract from that link:

```
MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as  
a “dummy date.” In some cases, this is more convenient than  
using NULL values, and uses less data and index space.  
To disallow '0000-00-00', enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.
```

So your db has not done this:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

This means you are allowing a zero date.

Comment: Replacing '0000-00-00' by 0 worked, thanks a lot for the help/information!